# Cannot upgrade 2SXC from 8.2.3 to 9.6.1

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke-8

I've tried several times to upgrade 2SXC content from 8.2.3 to 9.6.1 and keep running into an installation error.  This is a site that was previously on 7.2.2 and then upgraded to 9.1.1. I received the same error on both versions.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Go to the Extensions page in DNN 9.1.1 with 2SXC 8.2.3 installed
2. Upload and attempt to upgrade 2SXC to version 9.6.1

Expected Behavior:
The upgrade occurs without error.

Actual Behavior:
There is an error during upgrade, but the module appears to be upgraded when you reload the extensions page.

https://www.screencast.com/t/Y8Gk2ZuzLl

There are specific upgrade errors, but there are a large number of other errors cascaded as well.

```
2017-10-23 09:17:27,066 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:30][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Packages'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteScriptInternal(String connectionString, String script, Int32 timeoutSec)
ClientConnectionId:7df9af36-80ea-46e0-8760-f33a2536071b
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
2017-10-23 09:17:27,150 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:30][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Log.Logger - SQL Execution resulted in following Exceptions: 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Packages'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteScriptInternal(String connectionString, String script, Int32 timeoutSec)
ClientConnectionId:7df9af36-80ea-46e0-8760-f33a2536071b
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16

-- This SQL file is used for the app-module package (in .dnn manifest file) which must not be installed or upgraded if the 2sxc module fails to install

DECLARE @RequiredVersion int
SET @RequiredVersion = 9

DECLARE @RequiredVersionIsInstalled int
SELECT @RequiredVersionIsInstalled = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Packages WHERE Name = N'2SexyContent' AND CONVERT(int, LEFT([Version], CHARINDEX('.', [Version])-1)) >= @RequiredVersion) THEN CAST (1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST (0 AS BIT) END

If @RequiredVersionIsInstalled = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'2sxc 9 or newer must be installed for the app module to install. Probably something else went wrong while installing - see previous errors for more information. ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************', 16, 1)
    RETURN
END


2017-10-23 09:17:27,224 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:30][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Log.Logger - Installation Failed - Script
2017-10-23 09:17:27,634 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:30][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Log.Logger - Package Installation aborted
2017-10-23 09:20:32,338 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:9][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.ImportExportEnvironment.SaveOptions(Int32 zoneId) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Environment\Dnn7\ImportExportEnvironment.cs:line 186
   at ToSic.Eav.Apps.ImportExport.Import..ctor(Nullable`1 zoneId, Int32 appId, Boolean skipExistingAttributes, Boolean preserveUntouchedAttributes, Log parentLog)
   at ToSic.Eav.Apps.ImportExport.XmlImportWithFiles.ImportXml(Int32 zoneId, Int32 appId, XDocument doc, Boolean leaveExistingValuesUntouched)
   at ToSic.SexyContent.Installer.V8.Version080302() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Installer\V8.cs:line 105
   at ToSic.SexyContent.Installer.InstallationController.UpgradeModule(String version) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Installer\InstallationController.cs:line 187
   at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.UpgradeModule(String version) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 75
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.EventMessageProcessor.UpgradeModule(EventMessage message)
2017-10-23 09:21:34,131 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:11][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Framework.Reflection - ToSic.SexyContent.SexyContent
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'ToSic.SexyContent.SexyContent'.
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at DotNetNuke.Framework.Reflection.CreateType(String TypeName, String CacheKey, Boolean UseCache, Boolean IgnoreErrors)
2017-10-23 09:21:34,147 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:11][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.GetModulesForIndex(Int32 portalId)
2017-10-23 09:21:34,162 [UPENDO-PC1][Thread:11][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.Exception: Error Creating BusinessControllerClass 'ToSic.SexyContent.SexyContent' of module(2sxc-app) id=(3183) in tab(958) and portal(8) ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.GetModulesForIndex(Int32 portalId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.ThrowLogError(ModuleInfo module, Exception ex)
```

Has anyone else run into this, and do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually was resolved by adding the missing {databaseOwner} and {objectQualifier} tokens to the SqlDataProvider script.  It can be seen in the pull request below.

https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/pull/1363

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already found it - but check https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/upgrading-to-2sxc-9-3-requires-2sxc-7